# Cannot create XMLStreamReader or XMLEventReader from a DOMSource

Tags: java, security, jaxb, ws-security, xxe

I want to Unmarshaller of XMLStreamReader object but its give me error .

**my code like :-**

```
        SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) message).getSoapHeader();
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, false);
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);

        if (null != getDummyResponse()) {
            XMLStreamReader soapHeaderXsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(soapHeader.getSource());
            unmarshaller = JaxbUtil.getUnmarshaller(Dummy.class,Test.class);
            unmarshaller.unmarshal(soapHeaderXsr);
        } else {
            unmarshaller = JaxbUtil.getUnmarshaller(Test.class);
        }
```

**Error :-**

> com.dummy.exception.InvalidArgException: Unable to parse XMLjava.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot create XMLStreamReader or XMLEventReader from a javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource\n\tat com.dummy.connectors.SoapConnector.soapRequest(SoapConnector.java:54)\n\tat org.dummy.test.consumer.test.proccedLogin(test.java:180)\n\tat org.dummy.test.consumer.test.proceeddummyRequest(test.java:87)\n\tat org.dummy.test.consumer.test$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$46f53c92.invoke()\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\n

please give solution as fast as possible.

Thanks